# Positioned child won't display due to parent's overflow setting

Tags: html, css, css-position

Since the `parent` has `overflow-y` (which is a must in my real project) the `menu-item` will not display when hovering.

Is there any workaround so that the `parent` still has `overflow` settings and the `menu-item` will display when hovering as in my code?

```css
#parent {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
.menu-item {
  position: relative;
}
.menu-item:hover #popup {
  display: block;
}
#popup {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 108%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul id="parent">
  <li class='menu-item'>
    Menu Title 1
    <div id="popup">
      <p>Popup data</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>Menu 2</li>
  <li>Menu 3</li>
  <li>Menu 4</li>
</ul>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BLRBLk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The absolutely positioned pop-up is confined to the bounds of the [*nearest positioned ancestor*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Absolute_positioning). In this case, that's the `.menu-item` list item, which has `position: relative`.

This list item is a child of the `ul` with id `parent`, which has the `overflow-y: auto` rule that hides the pop-up.

One workaround is to remove `position: relative` from `.menu-item`.

This releases the pop-up from the confines of the `ul` and, with no other positioned ancestors, makes it relative to the initial containing block (and no longer subject to the parent's `overflow` rule).

```css
#parent {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
.menu-item {
  /* position: relative; */
}
.menu-item:hover #popup {
  display: block;
}
#popup {
  position: absolute;
  /* right: 108%; */
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  display: none;
  top: 10px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-200%);
}
```

```html
<ul id="parent">
  <li class='menu-item'>
    Menu Title 1
    <div id="popup">
      <p>Popup data</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>Menu 2</li>
  <li>Menu 3</li>
  <li>Menu 4</li>
</ul>
```